# Blur the background except shape of face detected (live video)

Tags: node.js, opencv

```
im.detectObject('./node_modules/opencv/data/haarcascade_frontalface_alt_tree.xml', {}, function(err, faces) {
    if (err) throw err;
    for(var i = 0; i < faces.length; i++) {
        face = faces[i];
        im.rectangle([face.x, face.y], [face.width, face.height], rectColor, rectThickness);
    }

    faces.forEach( function(face) {
        var faceIm = im.roi(face.x, face.y, face.width, face.height);
        faceIm.gaussianBlur([7,7]); //here i can blur the face(s)
    })
```

I have not seen any example about this feature, except the focus of camera of phone when onTouch the screen. I can blur the screen as the face(s), so it's like face + area = screen that means it's able to blur the area right ?

Answer (score 1):

To blur only the background, follow these steps:

1) Get the coordinates of the object to be detected, if the object is a face, you can use Haar cascades for detection. Check [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/d7/d8b/tutorial_py_face_detection.html). There are several ways to achieve this, so find whichever suitable for your purpose.

2) Keep a copy of the image, say img_copy, blur this image.

3) Now just do this:
img_copy[x_s:x_e,y_s:y_e] = Original_img[x_s:x_e,y_s:y_e]

where x_s,x_e,y_s,y_e are the start and end coordinates of the object(face)

Now img_copy will contain the result.

Hope this helps!

Comment: First of all thanks for answering my question. Your solution works really fine if the case is image. But my purpose is doing it with _live video_ (sure it will have some delay).

Comment: For videos, live or not, you will be getting frames which are images.